# Deploying Sinatra App on Dreamhost

Tags: deployment, sinatra, dreamhost

I'd like to deploy an app on Dreamhost, but couldn't find any relevant (or recent) guide on how to do so. Most related questions on this topic here are fairly old (+1 year or more), and seem to be from the pre RVM era (remember those days?.. :P).

I have SSH access and all that - anyone here done this (sinatra/rack app) and can provide some guidance? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this one](http://codex.heroku.com/past/2010/12/14/sinatra_on_dreamhost/)?

Answer (score 2):

If this is on a VPS (I am assuming since you have SSH access) you might want to look into Phusion's Passenger which simplifies deployment of ruby applications that use Rack. http://www.modrails.com/

Passenger includes an automated install script that can install your front facing proxying server (Nginx) and spit out the config used for each of your web apps.
To begin with Passenger just install the gem (gem install passenger) and then run the command it installs for you (passenger-install-nginx-module).

For further info check out https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/